# Ulogin: авторизация на каждой странице

Tags: редирект, ulogin, php, авторизация

Итак. Разобрался с предыдущими вопросами. Теперь вопрос появился насчет сервиса *ulogin*.
Есть код с этого сайта:

```
<script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,yandex,mailru;hidden=;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php"></div>
```

Есть также проверочный файл: check.php:

```
<?php session_start();

   $s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
   $user = json_decode($s, true);
   //$user['network'] - соц. сеть, через которую авторизовался пользователь
   //$user['identity'] - уникальная строка определяющая конкретного пользователя соц.  сети
   //$user['first_name'] - имя пользователя
   //$user['last_name'] - фамилия пользователя

   if (isset($user)) {

   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
   header("Location: index.php");
   exit;
}
?>
```

Однако идея-делать авторизацию на всех страничках сайта. Хочется-чтобы не было редиректа на *index.php*, а человек оставался бы на той же странице откуда он делал вход.
Нашел один способ-создать для каждой странички свой файл *check.php* со своим редиректом на себя же. Но этот способ требует кучу файлов...не совсем хочется это использовать. Может быть есть все-таки способ редиректа на ту же страницу откуда делался вход?

Comment: Как минимум убрать "header("Location: index.php");"
А лучше передать в этот скрипт адрес страницы, с которой осуществляется вход и написать "header("Location: $page");" например.

Comment: да. авторизация проходит. но теперь редирект остается на пустой странице: теперь редирект идет на модальное окно с иконками соц сетей. а не на сайт откуда шла авторизация

Comment: То есть редирект идет на эту страницу:
http://table/страница_откуда_авторизуемся#login

Comment: вот такой код у меня на страницах различных: <div id="login" class="reg"> <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a> <p class="outer-shadow1">Через какой сайт Вы бы хотели авторизоваться на нашем сайте?</p> <script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script> <div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,yandex,mailru;hidden=;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"></div> </div> </div>

Comment: до этого идет ссылка на это модальное окно. <a href="#login"><input type="button" value="ВОЙТИ ЧЕРЕЗ СОЦ. СЕТИ" id="button"/></a>

Comment: Если стоит header("Location: http://$page");

Тогда redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Тут убрать $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].

Если %3A%2F%2F пишется вместо :// тогда надо делать урлэнкод,  взять  и 
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page="<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
такое написать.

должно работать точно. Если не работает, конкретно на какой урл происходит редирект, а не описание куда

Comment: НЕТ. Все одинаково! Ничего не меняется. Редирект происходит на ссылку http://table/страница_откуда_авторизуемся#login отсюда мы и авторизуемся. Но надо чтобы ссылка была не http://table/страница_откуда_авторизуемся#login, а просто http://table/страница_откуда_авторизуемся.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем использовать вообще редирект авторизацию, когда uLogin поддерживает коллбэки?
Загляните в http://ulogin.ru/faq.php - там есть пример с коллбэком.

Comment: ...если бы еще понять как этак функция должна писаться..

Comment: здесь все понятно:
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,yandex,mailru;hidden=;redirect_uri=;callback=ucall"></div>

А что писать в файле check.php?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel; fields=first_name, last_name; providers=vkontakte, facebook, twitter, odnoklassniki, yandex, mailru; hidden=; redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"></div>


<?php session_start();
 $page=$_GET[page]
   $s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
   $user = json_decode($s, true);
   //$user['network'] - соц. сеть, через которую авторизовался пользователь
   //$user['identity'] - уникальная строка определяющая конкретного пользователя соц.  сети
   //$user['first_name'] - имя пользователя
   //$user['last_name'] - фамилия пользователя

   if (isset($user)) {

   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
   header("Location: http://$page");
   exit;
}
?>
```

P.S. Строка

```
"redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"
```

Показывает, что нужно выполнить скрипт `http://table/check.php`, при этом в этот самый скрипт передается *GET*-переменная '`page`', которая должна быть равная текущей странице. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` показывает что-то вроде "`site.ru`", а `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` показывает '`/page1`', в случае, если текущая страница - `http://site.ru/page1`.

В php скрипт приходит переменная '`page`'  которую мы используем в конце для перенаправления.

Comment: Тогда сделайте так:  
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,yandex,mailru;hidden=;redirect_uri=<? echo "http://".$_SERVER[PHP_SELF];?>"></div>

Я так понял, что в этом  месте передается адрес для преадресации.  $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] - показывает адрес выполняющегося в данный момент скрипта, т.е. текущей страницы. Если она php формата.

Comment: Тогда вместо echo "http://".$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; написать echo "http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page=".$_SERVER[PHP_SELF];
И в check.php код из ответа, заменив $page=$_POST[page]; на $page=$_GET[page];.

Comment: Исправил ответ, все должно работать, ничего менять не надо.

Comment: Еще раз обновил ответ.

Comment: я так глянул а urlencode не надо для redirect_uri делать?
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,yandex,mailru;hidden=;redirect_uri=<? echo urlencode("http://".$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]);?>"></div> 
Надо попробовать просто.

Comment: если так делать - то редирект получается на сайт ulogin.ru а уже потом адрес моего сайта

Comment: Ну ващ адрес допишите

<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,yandex,mailru;hidden=;redirect_uri=<? echo urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]);?>"></div>

Comment: Просто покажите где это скрипт. Как там он работает.

Comment: вот такой код у меня на страницах различных:
  <div id="login" class="reg">
  <div>
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
  <p class="outer-shadow1">Через какой сайт Вы бы хотели авторизоваться на нашем сайте?</p>
<script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,facebook,twitter,odnoklassniki,yandex,mailru;hidden=;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftable%2Fcheck.php?page="<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"></div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: до этого идет ссылка на это модальное окно.
<a href="#login"><input type="button" value="ВОЙТИ ЧЕРЕЗ СОЦ. СЕТИ" id="button"/></a>

Answer (score 0):

Зачем использовать header? Используй обычные формы с post php.

Comment: например как?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как у Вас работает добавление ссылки для редиректа, но у меня `GET` параметры просто не приходят и получить ссылку куда средиректить просто невозможно.

В общем я разобрался и сделал что у меня работает, костыли но все же.
Как мы можем видеть параметры в Ulogin передаются следующим образом:

```
data-ulogin="display=panel; fields=first_name, last_name; providers=vkontakte, facebook, twitter, odnoklassniki, yandex, mailru; hidden=; redirect_uri=check.php?page=**here_url_to_redirect_after_auth**"
```

Дело в том, что `GET` параметр тоже имеет знак `=`, в случае с `ULogin` он обрезается и всегда возвращается page пустой, т.е. ссылка получается вида `check.php?page`, естественно мы никуда и не можем перекинуть потом. Поэтому я просто использую название первого ключа из `GET` массива как URL для редиректа, а именно:

Получаем `check.php?here_url_to_redirect_after_auth`

в

```
GET['here_url_to_redirect_after_auth'] = '';

$referer = '';

if(isset($_GET))
{
    $get = array_keys($_GET);

    if(isset($get[0]))
    {
       $referer = $get[0];    
    }

}
```

Редиректим на `$referer` если не пустой или на главную в ином случае.

Ужасное решение, но работает.

**Вот еще решение используя колбек функцию**

**Javascript Callback function**

```
my_ulogin_callback(token){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', encodeURI('social?token='+token));
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
            //можно редирект а можно просто обновить текущую страницу
               window.location='УРЛ страницы на которой происходит авторизация - регистрация';                                    
       };
       xhr.send();
 }
```

**данные для ULogin**

```
data-ulogin="display=panel; fields=first_name, last_name; providers=vkontakte, facebook, twitter, odnoklassniki, yandex, mailru; hidden=; redirect_uri=;callback=my_ulogin_callback"
```

**Серверная часть**

В скрипте по адресу `/social` мы обрабатываем токен, получаем данные пользователя из соц сети, авторизируем его или регистрируем.

Comment: не является ответом.